# How to prevent the screen from locking in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lock-screen

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and would like to disable the lock screen. I have followed instructions to the change the turn off the `Screen Lock` option under `Settings -> Privacy > Screen Lock` (as so:)

[image]

but after a few minutes of idle time I am presented with a screen where I need to press enter to get my desktop back.

Usually I wouldn't be so lazy and would just press the enter button but I've noticed some other problem with Ubuntu 18.04 in that on occasion, after the screen locks, the desktop 'breaks' by presenting me with a purple, fuzzy and unresponsive desktop. My hope is that if I disable the locking behaviour I'll also stop the other problem.

Comment: In case people are wondering why one would want this: If you use Ubuntu in a VM you don't want to unlock your actual computer AND your VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Under `Power` Settings, called `Power Saving` -> `Blank Screen`